# Why does my buffered image not display in my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

I am trying to edit the pixels of a new buffered image but when I use the constructor for a new BufferedImage it does not display, when I load an image and set the pixels it does. Why does it not display?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int w = 1000;
    int h = 1000;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                          //ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/george/Documents/Ali.png"));

    int color = Color.BLACK.getRGB();

    for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            image.setRGB(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Your code above will be fairly long-running and thus does not belong within a paintComponent method. The only code above that should be in paintComponent are the first and last lines -- the super call and the `g.drawImage(...)`, and that's it. The image creation and altering code belongs elsewhere so it does not slow the perceived responsiveness of your program. Also never read in an image within paintComonent, not unless you want to subject your users to a painfully non-responsive GUI.

Comment: I am simply trying to create an image and want to know why the two ways produce a different result.

Comment: Regardless -- you're doing it all wrong, and so you should expect unexpected results. Editing an image within paintComponent is folly and risks making the paintComponent non-functioning. Start by doing it right, e.g., editing your image elsewhere, and then if it fails then, then show your corrected code.

Comment: Works fine for me, you might consider using `this` as the `ImageObserver` for `drawImage` and, frankly, `Graphics#fillRect` would be faster :P - But I also agree with HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 3):

Again, don't edit the BufferedImage from within paintComponent -- do it elsewhere. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageEdit extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int COLOR = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
    private BufferedImage image = null;

    public ImageEdit() {
        image = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for(int x = 0; x < PREF_H; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < PREF_W; y++) {
                image.setRGB(x, y, COLOR);
            }
        }        
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ImageEdit mainPanel = new ImageEdit();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageEdit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```